# The number of ways to distribute n ball in two boxes such that no box remains empty when

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Find the number of ways to distribute $n$ balls in two boxes such that no box remains empty when
>
> 1. both boxes are different
> 2. both are identical

**ANSWER**

1. I solved first part by using logic that each ball will have two options (Box 1, Box 2), and $n$ balls will have $2^n$ ways. But this will include 2 cases in which either box 1 or 2 is not filled. Therefore, it's answer will be $2^n - 2$.
2. What change will occur by identical boxes? According to me it's answer must be same as in (1), but in textbook the answer is $2^{n-1} - 1$.

Please explain me what changes will occur by using identical boxes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case makes an ordering out of the boxes. In other words, your result is an *ordered pair*, i.e. cutting $7$ objects, $(3,4) \ne (4,3)$.

If you cannot distinguish the boxes, the result is a set, and $\{3,4\} = \{4,3\}$ so the first answer for this case is a massive overcount, but by how much?

Comment: Sir I think if I just divide 1) answer with 2 ,I will get answer because corresponding to each number we will get one case

Comment: Thanks sir, for giving your precious time

Comment: @jamesamajoe yes, correct